# Using Matrix Multiplication to Rotate a cube in opengl

Tags: c, opengl, matrix, 3d

I have some code that draws a cube. I've managed to rotate the cube using glRotatef but I need to be able to rotate the cube using only matrix multiplication. I know what matrices to use but I'm not sure how to apply them to the vertices of the cube. Is there a way to pass a vector to glVertex3f? Or a way to pass an array of vertices?

Comment: you'll want to use shaders (in general and for this problem)

Comment: Could you go into more detail? I've only really just started with opengl

Comment: glRotatef, and glBegin, glEnd is deprecated, you should instead use vvertex buffer objects, if you want to find a good tutorial look for openGL version 3.2+

Comment: Do you want to transform the vertices as you render them? Or transform the stored geometry before rendering?

Comment: It needs to be able to change while the program is running in response to key presses but I think either of those would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree completely with Drew's answer.  However, I figured I'd point you in the direction of a nicely-written tutorial series that shows these concepts in action:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming

Start with the first 3 tutorials to learn shader basics, and then the 4th and 5th tutorials dive into rotation with triangles and cubes.  Also, the examples use FreeGLUT, which is a framework that allows you to easily interact with your code using key presses, mouse movements, mouse presses, and more.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenGL functions you're using are for immediate-mode rendering, and the vertex transformations are done within OpenGL. If you want to manually transform the vertices outside of OpenGL, you'll have to either implement `matrix * vector` multiplication, or use a library that does this for you.

As a side note, if you're just interested in rotation, you may find [Rodrigues' rotation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues'_rotation_formula) easier to implement than general matrix transformation.